# sbt project always fails on mac intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

What I've done is pretty simple, which is create a sbt scala project in Idea, and I'm using Mac.  My idea version is Ultimate 2017.2.

Right after the project is created, I got this error

```
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.BasicCommands$.$anonfun$call$5(BasicCommands.scala:203)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
```

This is my sbt file

```
name := "untitled"    

version := "0.1"    

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

What am I supposed to do?

**Update**

Well, I actually have not done anything more than upgrading Intellj Idea, and now it works...

Comment: Could be the [SCL-11404](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11404) / [SCL-11955](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11955) Make sure to use the latest IDE version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download with the latest compatible Scala plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable `use sbt shell for build and import` and it will work.

**Edit:** This option is in `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> SBT`

Comment: Oh, I see. That is `IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences` for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried creating an SBT project from Idea. Instead, I always create `build.sbt` first with a text editor and make sure it works with SBT directly without IDE.

Afterwards, you can just import your project using SBT plugin in Idea.

The fairly new option of building it with `sbt shell` works well on Mac, Linux and Windows.

Give it couple minutes to download dependencies and to index the project. You might need to restart your IDE if you just installed/updated your Scala/SBT plugin or if it refuses to recognise Scala syntax. It does work but takes patience sometimes.